# CakePHP 3, Stripe integration

Tags: php, cakephp, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate the Stripe API with CakePHP in the most simple way.  I loaded the Stripe's library via composer, and created a component (StripeComponent.php).  I'm trying to set it up and test the API request as this instructional: https://stripe.com/docs/development/quickstart

namespace App\Controller\Component;

```
use Cake\Controller\Component;
use Stripe\Stripe;

class StripeComponent extends Component
{
    protected $secretKey = " - My secret key  - ";

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        Stripe::setApiKey($this->secretKey);

    }

    public function makePayment()
    {
       return
        \stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
            'amount' => 1000,
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'receipt_email' => 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
        ]);

    }
}
```

I've called this component in a test controller

```
public function index()
{
    $this->loadComponent('Stripe');
    $payment = $this->Stripe->makePayment();
    $this->set('payment', $payment);  # trying to see output in view
}
```

I'm getting the error: `Class 'stripe\PaymentIntent' not found`

I tried to change the makePayment() to

$this->Stripe->PaymentIntent->create [...]  which yeilded this error: `Call to a member function create() on null`

Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The `Stripe` namespace starts with a capital `S`.

Comment: It's always the simple things.. thank you so much